# call jquery function from html without preventing default

Tags: jquery, html

So I saw a lot of answer on similar question but didn't found how to exactly make it work.
I have a lot of functions in query and all of them didn't complete because the html event load the next page. So what I need is how exactly make the html event wait till the jquery check everything that it should check.

so example of jquery is

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on("click","input[name=open]", function () {
        var login = $("input[name=field1]").val();
        var pas = $("input[name=field2]").val();
        alert('I call it');

        $.post("index.php", { 
            st: 1, 
            field1: field1, 
            field2: field2
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if ($.trim(data) == 'er') {
                alert("Sorry incorrect data");
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div>   
    <form method="POST" action="index.php?cd=in">
        <!----code here --->
        <div>
            <input name="open" class="field_submit" type="submit" size="7" value="IN" ">
        </div>
```

So the function works fine when there is not line with `action="index.php?cd=in"`. So what happen is just start the function but didn't wait the result and do redirection. So there is couple ways how I can prevent it:

1. redirect by jQuery but it not what I need
2. is make in HTML file on tag input event `onclick="return function-name();"`

But the problem how to correct realize the jquery file function because when I  put the function inside the console gives me an error as I the function is not defined. So the problem is how to exactly realize the function in jquery file that it work for onclick event in HTML file. Or if you know other better variant to realize it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is:

```
// bind submit event on form, not click of submit
// because a form can be submited without clicking submit button
$(document).on("submit", "form:has(input[name=open])", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent default behaviour
  var self = this; // keep ref on form
  var login = $(this).find("input[name=field1]").val();
  var pass = $(this).find("input[name=field2]").val();
  alert('I call it');
  $.post("index.php", {
    st: 1,
    login: login,
    pass: pass
  }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
    if ($.trim(data) == 'er') {
      alert("Sorry incorrect data");
      return false; // if error, return whatever value
    }
    self.submit(); // submit the FORM calling submit DOM API method (doesn't trigger jq submit handler)
  });

});
```

Comment: and what about HTML file ? some onclick event?

Comment: @alex_mike I don't understand what you mean?! Which `onclick` event?  EDIT: i edited answer because `this.submit();` must be `self.submit();`. It could be `this.submit(); ` only if passing `context: this,` as option of ajax request, which isn't possible using shorthand `$.post()` method

Comment: Oops, i forgot to prevent default behaviour, check it again now: `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: ok thanks, but some how it just skip the hole function I think I make some mistake

Comment: You mean submit event isn't triggered or what?

Comment: Maybe you are binding click event on submit which is already avoiding form to be submitted. Or maybe any error, check your console

Comment: console is fine, I do updates only with it. No mistake no warnings.

Comment: and I commented all other function, so it is only that one function left

Comment: @alex_mike Is your ajax request done? In your code, i just see `field1` and 2 are undefined. And if you remove this snippet, is your form submited?

Comment: no, even the alert didn't work, it skip the hole function.

Comment: If you provide any MCVE or online link, i could check it, otherwise it could be because of many reasons which i cannot be aware of. EDIT: maybe you are stopping submit event propagation in some way but as you said you removed all other script i'm really not sure. I just tested code and works as expected

Comment: ok take a look i copy code overe there https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zuRBBkJt7e

Comment: @alex_mike In your jsFiddle, you have invalid HTML markup and not including jQuery. once fixed, it works   http://jsfiddle.net/shn1xwnh/